# DAX Equivalent to SQL Statement

Tags: powerbi, dax

Can someone provide the DAX equivalent to the below sql statement? I am stuggling to reproduce this from my sql query.

```
SELECT COUNT(T1.Value) FROM myTable1 T1
JOIN myTable2 T2 ON T2.value = T1.Value
WHERE T2.Value = 'someValue'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to display this as a single card this becomes much easier. In fact, it doesn't require any DAX to execute. If you're trying to get one value you can select the COUNT option from the down caret in the "Values" field like so:

[image]

Filters can also be applied in the Filters pane to further limit your results. These filters can be of the column used in the visual or based on other columns from related tables in your data model. This requires you establish a data model in the Model page of Power BI desktop, but this is a necessity for creating visuals in Power BI.

[image]

---

If you need to apply this to a table that already has filters on it or otherwise shouldn't be filtered further then we'll need to use the DAX query which calculates the results of a clause that has been filters. In this case, you'd need the `CALCULATE()` and `FILTER()` clauses. You can embed them in each other like `CALCULATE( FILTER())`.

This is explained in much greater detail [in this Power BI article](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/the-filter-function-in-dax/). In this case, your query would look something like:

`CALCULATE(COUNT(T1.Value1),FILTER(T2, T2.Value = 'somevalue'))`